# Pandas Plotting with twinx

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm attempting to have a bar plot and line plot on the same figure using Pandas matplotlib API. However, it is not going very well. I am using twinx() which seems to be the generally accepted way of accomplishing this.

Note that this is done in a Jupyter notebook, with the plot being shown inline. Thank you for the assistance!

```
fig0, ax0 = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
ax1 = ax0.twinx()

trend_df_hours.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=color_list, ax=ax0)
trend_df_qty.plot(kind='line', secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
matplotlib.pyplot.close()
```

Answer (score 8):

What seems to be the problem?  Your code appears to work fine.

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

trend_df_hours = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))
trend_df_qty = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))

fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = ax0.twinx()

trend_df_hours.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=ax0)
trend_df_qty.plot(kind='line', secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: I found out the problem. I am using a date index (for both datasets), and it doesn't seem to like that. I could merge the datasets together, but then I don't think there's a good way to extract one column and plot it differently than the others. It can be done using the same plot style: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis

Comment: I was running into problems with `twinx` when using a date index; only one series would plot. Thankfully using `x_compat=True` fixed it (see [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14322)).